# Inotify - event->name gives subdirectories, not the main directories

Tags: c++, inotify

I have been writing a program to print the name of the file being accessed and the time the file was accessed. Basically, instead of getting the file path name that I type in, I am getting the names of all the subdirectories of the file. I strongly suspect that it has something to do with the event->name that I am using toward the end of the program. Is there some other function I should be using instead?

The code is as follows:

```
string filename;

printf("Please enter the file path name: ");
getline(cin, filename);
/*Create a List<string> for multiple files to be entered*/
list<string> stringlist;
list<string>::iterator it;
stringlist.push_back(filename);
it = stringlist.begin();

while(filename != "exit")
{
/*Check whether files exists. Prompt user to re-enter filename*/
while(FileExists(filename) == false )
{

    printf("File %s does not exist. Try again.\n", filename.c_str());  
    printf("Please enter the file path name: ");
    getline(cin, filename);
}
    printf("Please enter the next file: ");
    getline(cin, filename);
    if(filename != "exit")
    stringlist.push_back(filename); 
}

    int index = 0;
    wd = 0;
length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
while(i < length) {

struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[i];
    if(event->mask & IN_ACCESS)
    {
        log.WriteFile(event->name);   
    }
i+= EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
}
```

Comment: Ok, fellas - I found out from this site http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html that event->name returns the names of the files in the watched directory. It does not return the name of the directory itself. I am looking for a way to get the name of the directory being watched.

Comment: Essentially, I am looking for the path name associated with the event